# Redisを使ってのパブサブシステム

Tags: python

入門python3の３４９ページで下記のような二つのコードを書いているんですがエラーが出ます
これはどういうエラーなんでしょうか？　　並列処理のところのプログラムで同じようなエラーが出ます。
●redis_pub.py

```
import redis
import random

conn = redis.Redis()
cats = ['siamese', 'persian', 'maine conn', 'norwegian forest']
hats = ['stovepipe', 'boowler', 'tam-o-shanter', 'fedora']
for msg in range(10):
    cat = random.choice(cats)
    hat = random.choice(hats)
    print('Publish: %s wears a %s' % (cat, hat))
    conn.publish(cat, hat)
```

●redis_sub.py

```
import redis
conn = redis.Redis()

topics = ['maine coon', 'persian']
sub = conn.pubsub()
sub.subscribe(topics)
for msg in sub.listen():
    if msg['type'] == 'message':
        cat = msg['channel']
        hat = msg['data']
        print('Subscribe: %s wears a %s' % (cat, hat))
```

ターミナルで起動するとこういうエラーが出ます

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
$ python redis_sub.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tadashintaro/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 439, in connect
    sock = self._connect()
  File "/Users/tadashintaro/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 494, in _connect
    raise err
  File "/Users/tadashintaro/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 482, in _connect
    sock.connect(socket_address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tadashintaro/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2165, in _execute
    return command(*args)
  File "/Users/tadashintaro/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 563, in send_command
    self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
  File "/Users/tadashintaro/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 538, in send_packed_command
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/tadashintaro/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 442, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 61 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tadashintaro/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 439, in connect
    sock = self._connect()
  File "/Users/tadashintaro/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 494, in _connect
    raise err
  File "/Users/tadashintaro/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 482, in _connect
    sock.connect(socket_address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "redis_sub.py", line 6, in <module>
    sub.subscribe(topics)
  File "/Users/tadashintaro/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2229, in subscribe
    ret_val = self.execute_command('SUBSCRIBE', *iterkeys(new_channels))
  File "/Users/tadashintaro/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2161, in execute_command
    self._execute(connection, connection.send_command, *args)
  File "/Users/tadashintaro/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2172, in _execute
    connection.connect()
  File "/Users/tadashintaro/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 442, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 61 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 61 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.
```

`localhost:6379` への接続ができていないようです。
Redisサーバーは起動していますか？
以下のコマンドでredisプロセスがどのような状態か確認できます。

```
ps aux | grep redis
```

これでプロセスが起動していれば次のように表示されます。

```
redis    13319  0.0  0.0   2884  1056 ?        Ss   10:54   0:00 /usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

(Macのようなので表示は違うかもしれません）

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。プログラム初心者です。ps aux | grep redisの結果（　tadashintaro     5597   0.0  0.0  2432804    800 s002  S+    5:30AM   0:00.00 grep redis　）というふうに出ました。Redisサーバーが起動しているかわかりません。どうすればできますか？

Comment: Redisはなにもせずに自動的に起動するものではないです。起動させなければいけません。私はMacでRedisサーバーを起動させたことがないので、起動の仕方は回答できません。